# Advance to Non-sequential slide in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I am using LibreOffice Impress to play a video, and then when the video is done playing, go back to the "main menu" slide. I am using the "advance slide automatically after [duration of video]" option to achieve this. The problem is that this simply goes to the next slide, not slide 1 like I want it to.

Is there any way to make this happen? Even if it's semi-jurry rigged such as creating a blank slide afterwords?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can find would be to write [XSlideShowListener](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/presentation/XSlideShowListener.html) macro code.  An example is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=31312.

I could help you figure this out, although on superuser.com, programming-related answers probably aren't what you were hoping for.

Comment: thanks! programming works fine. I jury-rigged a solution into place though (using identical slides with hyperlinks after the video to the real slide), so it won't be necessary.